# ¿porque cuando imprimo en consola un array lo hace pero cuando quiero ingresar a su propiedad me da error?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-hooks

```
const { array } = useContext(myContext);

console.log(array)//[1,2,3,4,5]
```

hasta ahi todo bien el problema es que cuando hago lo siguiente:

```
console.log(array[0])
```

me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo una app mobile hecha en expo que funciona perfecto pero ahora que estoy pasandola a web me estanque en este problema, gracias desde ya!

Comment: ¿Para qué estás usando las llaves `const { array }`? Si esperas recibir varios valores, deberías usar corchetes `const [ array ]` para ["desestructurar"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment) los datos. Si solo vas a recibir un valor, basta con `const array`

Comment: deberias de meter el tag TypeScript que es lo que estas usando. y agregar la parte del codigo useContext o explicar mejor.

Comment: constumbre mia, no son necesarios en este caso.